# UINavigationController Style

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I created in code UINavigationController, but I want to change style to black translucent

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewControlelr alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navcon.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[navcon pushViewController:fvc animated:NO];
[self.window addSubview:navcon.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

But he doesn't change. Help me please!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that you're accessing a navigation controller's navigation controller. Your navigation controller doesn't live in another navigation controller, so you're setting the bar style of something that isn't there.

You want this:

```
navcon.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Also you can make a navigation controller and immediately initialize it with a root view controller so you don't have to push it in manually, like this:

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvc];
[fvc release];

navcon.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

[self.window addSubview:navcon.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

And yes, you forgot to release `fvc` in your own code.